# secure remote password SRP_set_authenticator()

Tags: srp-protocol

I am using secure remote password protocol in an embedded device that doesn't have a display to display username/pawword nor a keyboard to enter them. I have been told I can use SRP_set_authenticator() instead of SRP_set_params() which requires that I have pre-computed the SRP verifier.
My question is how to retrieve the SRP verifier for my username/password?
For information I have the SRP library running on MS Visual Studio I think it could help in retrieving the SRP verifier but I don't know how. is it simply by reading the verifier field of srp_st structure.
I promise to endorse you if I get the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I succeeded to have the verifier using the code below:      if(SRP_set_auth_password(srps, pass) < 0) {
  printf("srp_set_authenticator failed\n");
  return 1;
 }
 BigIntegerToBytes(srps->verifier, Verifier, 128);
 printf("Verifier = %s\n",
  t_tohex(hexbuf, (const char *)Verifier, 128));

Comment: This seems to be a question about C and some specific library or API which is an implementation of the SRP protocol. Can you tag your question with the name of the library so that others can easily find your question? If no suitable tag exists then add a comment and someone may create the tag for you.